# How to switch language in moment local react while switching language in whole website?

Tags: reactjs, date, locale

For example, I have in my **App.js:**

```js
moment().locale('en').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
```

**But I want it to switch on:**

```js
moment().locale('fr').format('MMMM Do YYYY');
```

While I am switching languages on the whole website

**Something like this:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";
import moment from 'moment';

const {i18n} = useTranslation();
const {languegeswitcher} = i18n;
const languegeswitcher  = () =>
{
    if (currentLang === "en") {
        return {moment().locale('en').format('MMMM Do YYYY')};
    } else if (currentLang === "fr"){
        return {moment().locale('fr').format('MMMM Do YYYY')};
    } else (currentLang === "ru")
        return {moment().locale('ru').format('MMMM Do YYYY')};
   
}
export default languegeswitcher;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the current format locale language on OS:

```js
const locale = new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
```

If you want to switch it on all websites, need to have a locale value in global as you had `currentLang`. Then use this value instead of `locale('en')`

```js
const locale = new Intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;

const localDate = moment(date);
localDate.locale = locale;     // localDate.locale(locale)

// or use your global value like this:
// localDate.locale = currentLang, localDate.locale(currentLang) 
    
localDate.format("MMMM D YYYY");
```